# Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider DictSrvProvider <- DictSrv <- MainCtrl

Tags: angularjs

I get this error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: DictSrvProvider <- DictSrv <- MainCtrl
```

even though all dependencies seem to be alright, and i'm using doing it the same way with other similar service and other controller and it works fine.

This is my service:

```
MyApp.service('DictSrv', function ($resource) {
    return $resource("/api/dictionaries/activities", {
        query: { method: "GET" }
    });

});
```

This is my controller:

```
MyApp.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, DictSrv)
{

    $scope.eventTypes = DictSrv.query();


})
```

Comment: Are you sure the DictSrv file is loaded in the browser? Also are you missing quotes around DictSrv in the controller injection?

Comment: Can you share the other controller that's working fine?

Answer (score 2):

This will work

```
MyApp.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope','DictSrv',function ($scope, DictSrv)
{
    $scope.eventTypes = DictSrv.query();
}])
```

Comment: It appears that your answer is not in sync with what the OP demands. Your answer targets the minification scenarios which is not mentioned in OP, hence, can not be a definite answer until specified.

Comment: 'DictSrv' was missing before function in Controller. So hope this will work.

Answer (score 0):

As Anzeo suggested, it sounds like 'DictSrv' might not be loaded into your index.html file.

```
<script src="./dictSrv.service.js"></script>
```